# English : English is shown as English (United States). Sitecore 8.2.1

Tags: content-editor

In Sitecore 8.2.1, by default, the langauge 'English : English' is shown as 'English (United States)' in the content editor. This behavior is confusing on our site as we use both the 'English : English' for default and 'English (United States) : English (United States)' for the US.

We also have a lot of other english versions, such as UK, India, South Africa and others.

We would now like to know if it is possible to change the shown text in Sitecore's content editor to actually show 'English : English' in order to clearly indicate which version of english the editor is currently working on.

Here is an image of the case:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like an issue that was fixed in Sitecore 9, issue number 162413:

> **Miscellaneous:** There was an incorrect caption for languages with a neutral culture in the Languages group in the ribbon.

If that's the case then Sitecore Support should be able to provide you with a fix.

Comment: I have contacted Sitecore support and they have indeed made a fix for me. Thank you for the tip :)